# How to add data to an array which was initialised in a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, instance

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dragon {


    private String[] interests = new String[4];

    public Dragon(String[] interes) {

        setInterests(interes);  
    }

    public void setInterests(String[] interes) {
        interests = interes;
    }
    public String[] getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dragon [interests=" + Arrays.toString(interests)"]";
    }   
}
```

Main class DragonMain

```
public class DragonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dragon test = new Dragon(args);

        test.setInterests(interes);

    }
}
```

I am not sure where I am meant to enter the data for the array as I keep getting errors.

Error:

> interes cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized array yet in main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dragon test = new Dragon(args);

    String[] interes = {"Xyz"};
    test.setInterests(interes);

}
```

Missing  + in string concatenation.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dragon [interests=" + Arrays.toString(interests)+"]";
    }
```

Comment: I have another problem. I get a [Ljava.lang.String;@7ba4f24f  error when I do test.getInterests()  . However if I add another dragon object (and add it to my friends) and then initialise the interests and print my friends at index 0, the dragon shows all of the correct information with its interests.

Comment: test.toString() Dragon string represenation, and test.getInterests().toString will give hash value of array from object class.

Comment: Ok I understand. TY